# Converting eval() to new Function()

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

Given an arbitrary `eval()`, is there a way to convert it to use `new Function()`, without breaking compatibility with any input (except for the change in scope)?

The only issue I can think of is that eval allows multiple statements, and returns the result of the last one, without having to add an explicit `return`. I cannot think of a way to emulate this with `new Function()`:

```
let code = '4; 5'
> eval(code);
5
> new Function(code)();
undefined
> new Function('return ' + code)();
4
> new Function('return (' + code + ')')();
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;
```

Is there something I am missing or is `eval()` incompatible with `new Function()` in this case?

Comment: What should the function return?

Comment: The same as the eval (5)

Comment: your code doesn't make sense

Comment: It's a short example to illustrate the incompatibility. Obviously '4; 5' is useless in practice, but it shows the issue with executing multiple statements

Comment: A function must accept something and return something. What should your function accept and what should it return?

Comment: Do you understand exactly what the eval does?

Comment: The issue is you can't.....

Comment: Are you trying to execute a javascript string through a function?

Comment: What's the actual problem you're trying to solve? Why do you want to convert `eval` to `Function` calls?

Comment: @Bergi, this is mostly out of interest. Originally the goal was to convert the eval to something a bit safer that didn't execute within the same scope. I thought it would be trivial to convert to `new Function`, but when I found out it wasn't I wanted to know why. Apparently [you can copy the eval to achieve this, but it's weird](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62158879/why-does-copying-eval-change-its-behaviour)

Comment: @SystemParadox Yeah, indirect eval might be the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is indeed impossible with `Function()`. The `eval` function is the only JavaScript feature that takes statement results into account.

Answer (score 0):

new Function() can indeed handle multiple statements...  but it can only operate on local vars and vars that are passed into it.. which means you can only return a single result.

```
var outerVar1 = 2;
var outerVar2 = 3;
var newFunc = new Function('a1','a2', 'var result = a1 * a2; return(result);');
console.log('Result = ' + newFunc(outerVar1, outerVar2));
```

The above works... the below doesn't... at least in most engines...

```
var outerVar1 = 2;
var outerVar2 = 3;
var newFunc = new Function('var result = outerVar1 * outerVar2; return(result);');
console.log('Result = ' + newFunc());
```