# Converting `eval` statements to functions (implicit return)

Tags: javascript, eval

I have developed a large number (>1000) strings that are intended to be fed into `eval`. I am trying to migrate away from using `eval`, as "eval is evil" and I'm generally trying to make things more secure. However, migrating from `eval` into a properly defined function is a little tricky, as [eval() returns the value of the last expression evaluated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62159509/converting-eval-to-new-function). This means that a string that was previously `eval`ed like this:

```
const stringToEvaluate = "x = 1; x + 1"
```

is difficult to migrate directly into a function, because the *last expression in the statement does not explicitly return anything*.
With regards to the string above, I might use `eval` in this way:

```
const y = eval(stringToEvaluate)
console.log(y) // 2
```

However, I can't use:

```
const y = (function safeFunction() {
   x = 1;
   x
})()
console.log(y) // undefined
```

as `safeFunction` does not return anything.

Importantly, **I am looking for a way to migrate these `eval` strings without needing to modify each individual string to include `return` statements in appropriate places**. This is because the large number of scripts would make this quite inconvenient. Also, the scripts can be more complicated than this, but this is a nice, minimal example.

Does anyone happen to know of any way to migrate these scripts into functions without needing to manually edit each of them? Also, this is one my first times posting to StackOverflow, so I welcome any feedback about ambiguity in my question! Thanks!

Edit:
Apologies for the ambiguity, another example of a "string" to be converted into a script is:

```
const stringToEvaluate = """
let x; 
if (
    $('.itemToFind').length > 0 &&
    $('.itemToFind').html().trim() != ''
  )
    $('.itemToFind del').html().trim();  <<< eval wraps either this
  else if ($('.price h4.offer-price').length > 0)
    $('.itemToFind').html().trim();      <<< or this
"""
```

(note that I have included the string across multiple lines to aid readability).

Comment: "These strings", "These scripts"?  A few examples would help.

Comment: @danh my apologies! I've added another.